# Redirecting from one angular app to another in ionic

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ionic-framework

I am currently converting an angularjs application into ionic, the angularjs project consists of two applications 1. Login app and 2. The actual app.

On running ionic serve, first the login app(localhost/login) is loaded, once the user has entered the credentials, the user is redirected to the actual application with a different url(localhost/app).

Is the same scenario possible in ionic and if it is, can anyone please tell how to achieve this?

Comment: For your reference: https://devdactic.com/user-auth-angularjs-ionic/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using `$stateProvider` and `$urlRouterProvider`

check this https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router tutorial

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider


        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })

        // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('about', {
            // we'll get to this in a bit       
        });

});
```

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/using-ui-router-navigate-ionicframework/

reefer this above tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the issue is that both the apps are separate angularjs applications, so I have separate app.js and system-config.js files for both the applications. In the web version, the redirection happens using the node server which I want to achieve using ionic server

Comment: @miteshpithadiya what i understand form your question is you need to make your own url in your ionic app for example to book mark a page am i correct

Comment: Currently in the web application, the login app is separated from the actual application using some routing or redirection in the node server, which means whenever the user logs in, the login app is discarded and the user is taken to a new application, hence the new app has its own app.js file. I want to replicate the same in ionic but am not able to figure out how to do it.